# Make custom field required in list

Tags: list, item

I have a contact list in my SharePoint but I have just the "Last Name" required.
How can I add more field to be required?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Go to Advanced Settings and **Enable the Allow management of content
   types**.
2. Now you will see the **content types** associated with the list under the **Settings section**.
3. Click on **Item**.
4. Select the **column**.
5. Check the **Required radio button**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Column Validation`.

1. Open List Settings
2. Click on the field
3. Scroll down and expand `Column Validation`
4. Use Formula - Replace `SiteColumn` with your column name

   ```
   =NOT(ISBLANK(SiteColumn))
   ```
5. Enter Error Message. For Ex: `Required Field`
6. Click OK